# Keep the first visable headerview’s uilabel’s textcolor = yellow when sliding the uicollectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I want to make the uicollectionview’s first visable headerview’s uilabel’s color is yellow and the other visable headerview is black when sliding the uicollectionview.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved perfectly, below I uploaded the demo:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == self.CollectionView) {
//Calculate the section with contentOffset
        CGFloat contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
        NSInteger lastSection = self.firstSection;
        if (contentOffset <= 0) {
            self.firstSection = 0;
        } else {
            for (NSInteger section = 0; section < self.playListArr.count - 1; section++) {
                contentOffset = contentOffset - (HEADER_VIEW_HEIGHT + (LINE_SPACING + CELL_HEIGHT) * ceil([(NSMutableArray *)self.playListArr[section] count] / 3.0) - LINE_SPACING);
                if (contentOffset <= 0 || section == self.playListArr.count - 1) {
//return the current first section:
                    self.firstSection = section;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
}
```